# Simple bash Question: combine results of 2 bash commands to one text file

Tags: bash, shell

I wish to put the results of "pwd" and "ls" into a text file. I have a directory with .jpg files and it and as opposed to "ls > filename.txt" I want the path of the files included in filename.txt, so that the result would be a list of lines, in a text file,  of the form "/home/path-to-files/file.jpg".

I know that it should be a combination of the "ls" command and the "pwd" command combined with a "/" in between.

This should be pretty easy to do but I am having a bit if trouble doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls` will print full paths if you pass it full paths. `*.jpg` expands to bare file names; `"$PWD"/*.jpg` expands to those same file names with the current directory prepended to each. `ls` then dutifully spits back the same paths you gave it.

```
ls "$PWD"/*.jpg > filename.txt
```

Alternatively, you could use the same trick with `find` if you want to search recursively through subdirectories:

```
find "$PWD" -name '*.jpg' > filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `readlink` or `find`:

```
readlink -f *.jpg > filename.txt
```

OR

```
find $(pwd) -name "*.jpg" -type f  > filename.txt
```

You can use `find` command to get the abolute path of the file by telling `find`to search into `$(pwd)` or `$PWD` , as these two will yield full path of the current working dir.